# Java : JLayeredPane resize problem

Tags: java, user-interface, jlayeredpane

I am writing a program GUI in java. I want to hava a JLayeredPane as ContentPane of my JFrame. On my JLayeredPane there are two layers : one layer a Canvas(canvas1) and another layer has a JPanel(jPanel5). I use Netbeans IDE and this code is generated:

```
    canvas1.setCursor(new java.awt.Cursor(java.awt.Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
    canvas1.setBounds(0, 0, -1, -1);
    jLayeredPane1.add(canvas1, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.PALETTE_LAYER);

    jPanel5.setBounds(0, 0, 670, 550);
    jLayeredPane1.add(jPanel5, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 670, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
    layout.setVerticalGroup(
        layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addComponent(jLayeredPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 553, Short.MAX_VALUE)
    );
```

pack();

when I run my program I saw a strange event! When I change size of tje JFrame; the size of main JLayeredPane did not change. I used diffrerent backGround colours for components and it is obvious to me that the size of JLayered is permanent however I set it vertical and horizonal resizable in it's properties. The JFrame is resizable but main jLayeredPane's size is permamnet.

How can I cause the jLayeredPane to resize as my JFrame ?!

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the default BorderLayout instead of the GroupLayout you're using now. Simply comment out the group of lines that start with creating the GroupLayout and add this line:

```
getContentPane().add(jLayeredPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

The BorderLayout.CENTER parameter to the .add() method tells the BorderLayout manager that you want the given widget to fill the center of your window.

Comment: Thank you But adding this code in generated code of netbeans is impssible. How can I set his in JLayeredPane properties ?

Comment: Don't use Netbeans to generate the code. Read the Swing tutorial (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) which has plenty of examples of how to create your own GUIs so you aren't dependent on the IDE.

Comment: Once you have your project working, you can take your source out from your IDE and tweak it to fix all the problems your IDE caused.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the JLayeredPane along with the JFrame.
While in (NetBeans IDE) Design mode - right click on the JLayeredPane, then on the popup menu hover over "Auto Resizing", then check bothe verticaland horizontal.
That way the size of the JLayeredPane will change relatively to the JFrame.